# python optimize list search

Tags: python, list, optimization

So take the following example list

```
l = [
    {
        'post':1,
        'user':1,
        'other_stuff':'something',
        'more':'you get the point'
    },
    {
        'post':1,
        'user':2,
        'other_stuff':'something',
        'more':'you get the point'
    },
    {
        'post':2,
        'user':1,
        'other_stuff':'something',
        'more':'you get the point'
    },
]
```

I need to be able to check if a `'user'` is already connected to a `'post'`, and I could do it with looping:

```
user = 1
post = 1
response = False
for connection in l:
    if connection['post'] == post and connection['user'] == user:
        response = True
        break
```

and that works very well. The issue is that in the actual situation, `l` will be populated 1.5 million times, and this iteration will run every time it populates since it needs to check to see if something already exists. so the last 500k iterations will be iterating through a list of over 1 million dictionaries. **There is no way that this is the most efficient method for this!**! My question is: what would be an optimal method that would not require such exhaust?

note: I do not necessarily know the values of the other keys in the dictionaries so I cannot do `if x is in l` to check

Comment: Could you put this into a database as these `l` values come in?  Then you can run queries against the database without needing to iterate over all the rows yourself.

Comment: I could, but I was hoping for a pythonic solution

Comment: in reality, I will most likely use a database since python will always be slower in this regard, but in other projects I work on I may not be able to use a database and an optimal search_like method for comparing a list of dictionaries would be useful

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd reconsider how you are laying out your data structure. If you need to have efficient access on a `post` and `user` pair, I'd consider storing it in a format like the following:

```
l = { (1, 1) : {'other stuff':'something', ...}, 
      (1, 2) : {'other stuff':'something', ...},
      (2, 1) : {'other stuff':'something', ...} }
```

Then this becomes an `O(1)` lookup:

```
user_post_pair = (1, 1)
if user_post_pair in l:
    # Stuff...
```

Comment: Using `l` for variable names. Gotta love it :)

Comment: And if for some reason you can't control the input to begin with, you can convert it into this format as it comes in.

Comment: I have considered that, the only issue I have with it is that this list is being accessed in a couple other places, and the way it is set up for those makes it much simpler...I may as well make a copy and store two separate objects, a list and dictionary.

Comment: @Keeler Yeah, I agree. I've kept it since the OP used it, and I'm assuming it's not *actually* used in the code. At least I hope not...

Comment: @Yuushi don't worry it's not

Comment: @Yuushi Still upvoted anyway. :) Despite the variable name, this is a suggestion that should definitely be taken seriously.

Comment: @Yuushi I used a method branched off of yours, so I accepted your answer. Because the full dictionary structure is much more useful in most of my other situations, and since I am aggregating the actual list, I created a `for_checking` list that was a list of the tuples so that searching is efficient! Thanks

Comment: @Keeler I'm glad that you would not not upvote an otherwise excellent answer simply because you didn't like the variable name used.  I'd hope that most users would be able to look at an example and substitute their own variable for the one used in the example.